# Can't run react-native-youtube on Ubuntu + Android

Tags: react-native, npm, youtube

I am trying to make react-native-youtube by davidohayon669 run locally on my Ubuntu + Android. I installed it with following command in my react native app:

`npm install react-native-youtube -S`

Unfortunately I get following error message when starting the app.

`Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "ReactYouTube" was not found in the UIManager.`

I am not quite sure what is the reason for this and have a hard time debugging it, as I am quite new to react native. Any help how to debug it better is also greatly appreciated.

To debug this I tried installing the react-native-youtube example app, but get issues with installing pods. This seems weird to me as I am running Ubuntu 18.04.4 and as far as I know pods are a thing for OSX.

```
> ReactNativeYouTubeExample@2.0.1 postinstall /home/ml/p/deleteit/react-native-youtube/example
> cd ios && pod install && cd ..

Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:308:in `activate_bin_path'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:289:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem cocoapods (>= 0.a) with executable pod (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ReactNativeYouTubeExample@2.0.1 postinstall: `cd ios && pod install && cd ..`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ReactNativeYouTubeExample@2.0.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2020-07-05T08_46_58_220Z-debug.log
```

Not sure if this part is related to the same issue and can help debugging it.

Comment: If you're only trying to run on Android you can skip the pod install step.

Comment: This error happens during npm install. Do you know how I can do skip it?

Comment: What does your `package.json` file look like

Comment: Thank you! This is the package.json and I deleted postinstall from there: 
https://github.com/davidohayon669/react-native-youtube/blob/master/example/package.json

Comment: Unfortunately the example app still crashes saying, 'Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered'. I believe that the example app is too unstable at this point and too far off the actual problem.

Comment: Are you using using Expo or the React Native CLI? Because it might be an Expo related problem. I got it working using the cli.

Comment: I am indeed using Expo and not quite sure how to run in on react-native cli instead. I will try it out and see if there are any changes. Thank you